# Javascript Transition on Submit of Form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Javascript to submit a form. All works well but when the person clicks "Submit" I want the form to fade in a simple message. All it needs to do is change the CSS to fade out the form and fade in message. Nothing complicated but I do not know jQuery or javascript well enough to implement this.

Here is the code for the form:

```
<div id="Voicemail">
<input class="vinput" type="text" id="cid_name" />
<label class="vlabel">Your Number</label>
<input class="vinput" type="text" id="cid_number" />
<input class="light_button custom_button" type="submit" name="Voicemail" 
       onclick="send_call()" value="Leave A Voicemail" />
</div>
```

This is the DIV I want to fade in:

```
<div id="success-call" class="hide">
<p>You will receive a call momentarily</p>
</div>
```

This is where I am confused. How do I fade out the form and fade in the Success Message.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6QJt/3)

---

```
function send_call(){
    $("#Voicemail,#success-call").fadeToggle();
    // other stuff
}
```

That'll do it using jQuery

Comment: If you change `$("#Voicemail,#success-call").fadeToggle();` to `$("#Voicemail").fadeToggle(function(){
        $("#success-call").fadeToggle();
    });`, you don't get the annoying jerky effect.

Comment: True.  Mine is asynchronous, but this is probably what the poster is really asking for.

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't get it to work at first then I realized I had jQuery 1.4.1 and need 1.4.4 for the toggle to work. Thanks for the help works great now!